# Can I specify both source port and (target) port in one firewalld rich rule?

Tags: firewall, centos8, firewalld

I want to add a rich rule to allow access to a target port from specific source port, I tried to add the rule like this:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.1.x" source-port port="1234" protocol="tcp" port port=80 protocol="tcp" accept'
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.1.x" source-port port="1234" protocol="tcp" service name="http" accept'
```

And I just get error like：

```
Error: INVALID_RULE: more than one element. There cannot be both 'source-port' and 'port port="80" protocol="tcp"' in one rule.
```

Can anyone help to find a way to add a rich rule with source ip, source port and target port at the same time?

thank you.

Comment: And in the firewalld man page, or redhat firewalld document page, I don't see any content about cannot use source port and port at the same time.